# c header files suddenly missing

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Somehow the standard C header files seem to have gone missing.

/usr/include/ used to include inttypes.h, sys/types.h, stdlib.h, string.h and a myriad of other standard C files.

locate still shows these files present in /usr/include until I ran updatedb.

How do I recover these files? I tried re-installing gcc using apt-get.

Comment: Are you sure the headers have actually been removed? What is the output of `find /usr/include -name "*.h" | wc -l`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have uninstalled the package that supplied those files. The package might have been uninstalled as it was no longer needed - marked as automatically installed by some other package.

Check the package that contains the files on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and install the package that contains the file.

[Search result for `inttypes.h`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=inttypes.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=saucy&arch=any)

Comment: Thanks, @Grzegorz. This was the cure. sudo apt-get --reinstall --fix-missing install libc6-dev fixed it.